# Will `FileWriter` cause out of memory?

Tags: java-threads

Since the bottom layer of `FileWriter` is implemented with `FileOutputStream`, I use the following code in a small case of copying a txt file:

```
public class FileWriterLearning {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "D:\\IdeaProjects\\IOStreamLearning\\assets\\test.txt";
        String targetPath = "D:\\IdeaProjects\\IOStreamLearning\\assets\\test_copy.txt";
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(targetPath,true);

            char[] buffer = new char[16];
            int readLen = 0;
            while ((readLen = fileReader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fileWriter.write(buffer,0,readLen);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                // The essence is not to read the whole memory and then write it as a whole, then the problem of memory cannot be guaranteed while reading and writing.
                fileReader.close();
                fileWriter.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code, I adopted the program of reading and writing to prevent the file from being too large to be read at one time, which would cause insufficient memory, The data of the file is finally stored in the memory, if the file is too large It may still cause insufficient memory, so is it useless to prevent all file data from being read into memory while reading and writing? If so, what are the solutions for handling large file reads and writes?

Answer (score 0):

`FileWriter` uses a buffer internally. The bb in the above figure is the buffer, and the internal hb is an 8k byte array. When the `FileWriter.write` method is called, the buffer is written first. When the buffer is full When the `write` method of `OutputStream` is called internally to write to the file, there is no need to worry about the problem of insufficient memory

If you want to directly write to the file after reading the data each time, you can call `flush` or `flushBuffer` after `write` to directly flush the data in the buffer and write it to the file.